# PowerShell SqlDataAdapter issue

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to pull data in to a dataadapter but I am getting the following error, *Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."*
From reading the info on the error message is says I am not assigning the dataconnector correctly but I think i am as the same code works to pull the data in to a table.

Here is the code, can someone tell me what I am getting wrong please?

```
$serverName = 'server\SQLEXPRESS';
$databaseName = 'db';
$tableName = 'table';
$UserName = 'sa'
$Password = 'Password'
$ServerConnection = "Data Source=$serverName; user id=$UserName; password=$Password;Initial Catalog=$databaseName;"
#
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString=$ServerConnection
$connection.Open()
$SqlQuery = 'Select *  FROM table WHERE table.mailed = 0 ORDER by SessionID'
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $SqlQuery

$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$da = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter $SqlQuery
$da.fill($dt)

$connection.Close()
```

Comment: Pass `$command` to the constructor of the data adapter, not `$SqlQuery`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you, I knew it had to be something easy I wasn't getting my head around